# Deklination bei Nomen die auf -er enden

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-case

Wird bei Nomen die auf -er enden, bei einer Verwendung eines Dativs oder Akkusativs in der Mehrzahl immer ein "n" hinten angehängt?

Ein Beispiel wäre folgender Satz:

> Viel Spaß mit deinen neuen Büchern.

Gibt es eine entsprechende Regel und allenfalls Ausnahmen?

---

EDIT: Question in english

If a noun that ends with *-er* is used as accusative or dative case in plural, is always a 'n' added to the word?

Example:

> Viel Spaß mit deinen neuen Büchern.

Is there a rule about when the 'n' is added at the end of the word and if so, are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: In my German classes, the Dozent called these *n-words*. Herr is another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die in der Frage getroffene Annahme, dass bei `-er`-Plural Dativ und Akkusativ Plural ein `-n` angehängt wird, trifft bei starker Deklinationsklassen (S2) nur für den Dativ Plural, nicht aber für den Akkusativ Plural zu.

Beispiel:

> Ich verdanke mein Wissen den Büchern. *Dativ mit -n*
>   Ich gebe die Bücher morgen zurück. *Akkusativ ohne -n*

Es gilt folgende Regel für die Plural-Deklination im Deutschen:

- Im Plural sind Nominativ, Genitiv und Akkusativ stets identisch:

> N: die Tage - G: der Tage - A: die Tage
>   N: die Bücher - G: der Bücher - A: die Bücher
>   
>   Im Dativ Plural wird in allen (starken und schwachen) Deklinationsklassen ein `-n` bzw. `-en` zum Nominativ Plural hinzugehängt.

Bei schwachen und Misch-Deklinationsklassen werden allerdings alle Plural-Fälle auf gleiche Weise mittels `-n`-Suffix gebildet:

Beispiel *der Bauer:* (schwache Deklination W1)

```
die Bauern
der Bauern
den Bauern
die Bauern
```

Eine ausführliche Behandlung aller Deklinationsklassen findest du im [Wikipedia-Artikel zur Deklination in Deutsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Schwache_und_gemischte_Deklination).